# What kind of tape is on this motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, laptop-repair, microsoft-surface

Recently I was replacing the screen on my Surface Book 2, and I mistakenly removed some kind of tape from the back of the motherboard. The tape I removed does not seem reusable, so I'm trying to figure out what I will need to replace it with. It looks like a fabric of some kind and the exposed side is somewhat "crunchy" or spongy, and this image seems to show the exact same kind of tape intact on a Surface Book 1 motherboard:

[image: Surface Book 1 motherboard]

The best I can tell, it is probably some kind of conductive tape (graphite maybe?), and further speculating it's something of a grounding strap, but I really am not sure. So far I've searched and found numerous different types of such tape, and none that I found look quite right from the product images at least. Please help?

Edit: Two more photos to make it a bit clearer

This is where the tape was on the motherboard, and there is still residue from it in place:
[image: Where the tape was on the motherboard, residue still in place]

And this is the section of tape itself:
[image]

Comment: If it was spongy, it was most likely some sort of impact protection, and nothing conductive. But, it could also be a shielding gasket https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/shielding-strips/7737122 to shield from electrical interference.

Comment: so it's not spongy like a foam, it's more of a crinkly kind of texture- it feels almost like the surface of felt, but made of something shiny and metallic. It makes me suspicious especially that the entire tape strip is going across an exposed line of metal on the motherboard. I would believe it's some kind of impact pad, but then why wouldn't it be something more typical like foam? Attaching another few photos to hopefully make it clearer what I'm looking at

Answer (score 2):

It is shock resistant tape, which protects from damage from normal daily movement. Sometimes called "red tape" in the repair industry, iFixit suggests Tesa 61395 Tape in their Surface repair guides.

Comment: it looks like 61395 is a double-sided tape while this is only single-sided, is there a different tape to use for that?

Comment: in fact, it seems like this type of tape is the wrong kind altogether. I believe 61395 is for things like mounting a screen, not for whatever purpose this is for. this is much much thinner, and appears to be somewhat metallic (at least, it is shiny on the back)